# Convertir el tipo fecha DD-MM-YYYY a DD-MM-YY en AS400 iSeries

Tags: php, base-de-datos, as400

Buenos días.

Realizando un formato de fecha en As400 me doy cuenta que con DAY - MONTH - YEAR, realizando el orden que desee funciona pero siempre me va arrojar 01-09-1995 pero lo que deseo que me muestre ahora es 01-09-92. ¿Alguien ha realizado un formateo para que quede de esa manera?, Agradezco la ayuda. Muestro un ejemplo que estoy haciendo con AS400 y php.

```html
$campos.="DAY(".$campo_nombre.")|| '-'|| MONTH(".$campo_nombre.") || '-' || YEAR(".$campo_nombre.") AS FEC_".$id_campo.",";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías probar lo siguiente en PHP:

```
$campos.="DAY(".$campo_nombre.")|| '-'|| MONTH(".$campo_nombre.") || '-' || YEAR(".$campo_nombre.") AS FEC_".$id_campo.","; // Obtenes la fecha
$fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', campos); // Obtenes una fecha a partir del formato especificado
echo $fecha->format('d-m-y'); // Lo imprimis con el nuevo formato
```

Espero que te haya servido. Cualquier cosa avisanos.

Saludos!